# Understanding Ruby (Sinatra) - very very basic

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I was looking at Sinatra and trying to understand the syntax:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello, World!"
end
```

I understand it does this:

> This is a ‘Route’. Here, we’re telling Sinatra that if the home, or root, URL '/' is requested, using the normal GET HTTP method, to display “Hello, World!”

But what is happening the Ruby language?

1. What does this syntax mean: `get '/'`? Is `get` a method and '`/`' a parameter to it? If it is method, then in Ruby, I can call a method as `methodname (parameter) {}`. What is `{ }` there for?
2. I usually understand `do` and `end` as `{ }`, which are kinds of enclosures to function bodies.
3. Between `do` and `end` we have "Hello, World!" so is it a statement? What I mean is, it is getting printed, but we did not call it as `print "Hello, World!"`, so what is going on?
4. It seems `get` is a method defined in Sinatra, but if I add a gem, where there is a `get` method already defined, then how do I know which 'get' method it would call? Or, does it refer to the HTTP `get` method?

I am sorry if this question sounds very basic, but I want to get through it before I move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest going through a tutorial on ruby before tackling a larger problem like `sinatra` which is a fairly specialized library.

A good place to start is with the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/)

As for your questions.

1. `get` is a method. `'/'` is its argument. and `do ... end` denotes a block in ruby just like `{}` would.
2. Yeah that's what `do ... end` are
3. Blocks in Ruby return the last value calculated by default so in the is case having a string is the same as having `return "String"`.
4. If you are getting a namespace collision, Ruby will complain. In this case `get` is the `sinatra` defined method `get`. Abstractly it stands for an `HTTP GET` request against the server.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the tutorials, but no where you get the explanation of such syntax so granular. I am sure, over the period of time, upon experience, I will catch them easily. Usually in most of the  language, a method call look something like methodname(paramaters). But here methodname(parameters) and then {}. That gets me lost. It calls get method , in which it pass parameter "/" and also it append a block, that returns "hello world". So how this block may have been used wherever get method has been defined? method calls are is just methodmname and parameters, isn't it?

Comment: @JVK, Using '{' and '}' to define the body of something is common in languages, you just haven't written in C, C++ or Perl, to name three, where you'd see braces. We call what's inside '{' and '}' or 'do'/'end' a block.

Comment: @JVK A block is one of the parameters (always the last one) from a method call. It gets invoked when the method `yield`s.

Comment: Thank you all. I wish I would have seen this explanation earlier http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/ that exactly explain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For the "perfect" response, I suggest you have a look at the book "Sinatra Up and Running" by 
Alan Harris and Konstantin Haase.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019664.do

Pages 6 and 7 explain how the line "get '/' do" is in fact a method call.

And you can view this 2 pages with Google Preview.